# Помогите корректно посчитать значения в Проекте Отчетов Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

[image: Пример таблицы]
На входе есть некоторые данные (код факультета, Название предмета, код кафедры...), нужно посчитать количество кафедр с лидирующем числом мест для каждого факультета.
На примере их картины выходят следующие данные с таким кодом, где у математики есть две лидирующих по количеству мест позиций - 283, то есть в итоге "Лидирующих кафедр" должно быть две, а не одна:

```
=Count(Max(Fields!Количество_мест.Value))
```

[image: Исходный код]

**Очень прошу Вас помочь!**
**Решение нужно для Reporting Services**
Мой код изложенные выше не выдаёт нужного результата, так как при двух и более одинаковых максимальных количеств мест он выдаёт "1",когда ожидается "2" и более.

Comment: Определитесь, для чего нужно решение. MySQL? SQL Server? Visual Studio (какой язык)? Reporting service?

Comment: посчитайте эти макс. значения по кафедрам или чему-то там. а  потом приджойньте обратно, по условию  равенства значения и найденного максимума. получите те, у кого максимальное, хоть оно там одно, хоть несколько

Comment: Уточнил условия в посте.